# Docker Build CMD fail yum not able to install the requirements

Tags: docker, dockerfile

My docker build cmd is failing to create an image using Dockerfile. It shows this error

[here is the screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wyj99.png)

Comment: Please edit your question and add the errors in question. Also run `cat /etc/resolve.conf` in your host to see if you have any resolver.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if you can access the site on the host machine.
2. Check your docker networking, for a docker VM, it is usually a bridge network by default.
3. Check if you need to add the repository to YUM.